# Get the usage timestamps for previously connected external devices in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, timestamp, peripherals

How can I get timestamps on previously connected External devices for a specific port?
(Usage Start Time and Usage End time)

**I have tried this but, i am only getting USB list**, I need all the external devices are connected History on a specific port

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational' |Where-Object {$_.ID -eq 2003 -or $_.ID -eq 2102} | Select-Object @{Name='TimeCreated';Expression={$_.TimeCreated.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}}, ID, LogName, MachineName, Message, Opcode, OpcodeDisplayName, ProviderId, ProviderName, RecordId, Task, TaskDisplayName|ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Have you connected any other types of external devices since the earliest event in the log? Perhaps you'll want to configure the event log channel to have a bigger file size...

Comment: Yes I have connect 1 Monitor to the laptop, but it is not under 2003 and 2102 event id's
I want to track any kind of external devices that are connecting to laptop need to find it.

Comment: You probably want `Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceId 6416` that fires whenever any external device is connected.